# Two threads accessing a locked mutex simultaneously

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have written this code in C language and there are two pthreads that are using this code and trying to access the mutex "firstSection" (in both of them we are sure that the mutex passed to function is the same). The code suppose to check two mutexes, and if both of them were available, performs some actions which take place in function safeUnlockTwoMutexes(), and if failed to acquire at least one of them, it has to wait for two seconds and tries again. ("intersection" mutex is the main-lock to safe check the situation of the other mutexes)

```c
    void twoSectionRoute(pthread_mutex_t firstSection, pthread_mutex_t secondSection){ 
        bool pathClear = false;  
        while (!pathClear){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&intersection);
            if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&firstSection) == 0){
                if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&secondSection) == 0){
                    pathClear = true;
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&intersection);
                } else {
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&firstSection);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&intersection);
                    sleep(2);
                }
            } else {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&intersection);
                sleep(2);
            }
        }
        safeUnlockTwoMutexes(firstSection, secondSection, 1);
    }
```

Now the problem with this code is both threads are able to lock the mutex "firstSectio" at almost same time and I don't know why. (maybe because its type is recursive mutex?! I've used "PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER" in the beginning of the file as global variables)

I'm wondering how can I fix this issue, and the threads access this sections one after another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function signature passes `pthread_mutex_t` values `firstSection` and `secondSection` by value. You need to pass mutexes by pointer.

```
void twoSectionRoute(pthread_mutex_t* firstSection, pthread_mutex_t* secondSection){
```

Then, within the function use just `firstSection` and `secondSection` rather than `&firstSection` and `&secondSection`.

If you pass the mutex by value (as here), and it compiles, then the mutex itself is copied, so you end up with undefined behaviour and the mutex locks do not operate on the same state.